# Validate a form on click of button Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitAndConfirm').on('click', function() {
        alert("Hi");
        $('#addPat').validate({
            rules:{         
                iscosId:{required:true},
                pat_id:{required:true},
                admissionDate:{required:true},
                dischargeDate:{required:true},

             },messages:{
                iscosId:"Please reload the Page",
                pat_id:"This field cannot be empty",
                admissionDate:"This field cannot be empty"
             }
        });
     });
 });
```

From the above code I have to validate the form after the click of a button but it doesn't work, can anyone please help me?

Comment: do you get the alert "Hi"?

Comment: do see any console error in firebug?

Comment: I am pretty sure the validation plugin works differently and you should not be setting it onclick. Not knowing what validation plugin it is, it is pretty hard to help out.

Comment: Also if possible NEVER assign a click handler to the submit button. You have the submit event of the form to use for that. In your case you need to do `$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#addPat').validate({ .... }); });`

Answer (score 0):

can you try this approach.you can check the input fields if empty AND trap also white space/s. Add a class to all input fields , e.g. class="required" and add attribute fieldname with respective value for each input field.

```
 var requiredFields = "";
    $("#myForm").find('.required').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
            requiredFields += " - " + $(this).attr("fieldname") + "\n";
        }
    });

    if (requiredFields != "") {
        alert("Please enter the following required field(s): \n" + requiredFields);
    } else {
        //save here
    }
```